# Captura de datos Tkinder(Boton y OptionMenu) hacia la base de datos(POSTGRESQL)

Tags: python, postgresql, tkinter

hoy tengo un problema el cual me gustaría plantearles me encuentro haciendo un formulario en python que utilice como base de datos POSTGRESQL, me esta dando un error debido a que cuando quiere acceder a la información del optionmenu dice que es una tupla, y no esta obteniendo el dado que yo elegí, también va lo mismo para un botón que tiene como adjunto una imagen no se como guardarla en la base de datos que función de usar para esto, por favor me podrían ayudar?

**Actualizacion**: acabo de notar que tenia una coma de mas pero ahora aparece otro error **psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type '_tkinter.Tcl_Obj'**

**Esta es la declaración del menú desplegable**

```
        self.var1 = StringVar(self.frame)
        self.opcion1 = OptionMenu(self.frame, self.var1, *ArrayComercial, command=self.getOpcion1)
        self.opcion1.config(width=20)
        self.opcion1.place(x=200, y=240)
```

**Esta es la declaración para el boton que guardara la imagen adjunta**

```
self.botton_ComproPago = Button(self.frame, text="Adjuntar", command=self.AbrirArchivo) 

self.botton_ComproPago.place(x=200, y=380)
```

**Funcion para buscar elegir la imagen**

```
        def AbrirArchivo(self):
               archivo = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="abrir", initialdir="C:/", filetypes= 
              [["Archivos de Imagen", "*.jpg"]])
              print(archivo)
```

**Botón para guardar la información**

```
        self.botton_Guardar = Button(self.frame, text="Guardar", 
            command=lambda:self.GuardarFormulario(
            self.entry_NumeroPresu.get(),
            self.entry_Cliente.get(),
            self.entryFecha.get(),
            self.opcion1,
            self.opcion2,
            self.botton_ComproPago.cget('command'),
            self.botton_ComproProove.cget('command')
            
            ))
```

**Función de la conexión con la base de datos**

```
    def GuardarFormulario(self, Numero_Pres, Cliente, Fecha_Soli, Comercial, Asistente, 
        Compro_Pago, Compro_Proveedor):
        conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname="postgres",
                         user="postgres", 
                         password="pass", 
                         host="localhost"
                         )
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        query =  "INSERT INTO 
        Formulario(NumeroPresu,Cliente,Fecha_Solic,Comercial,Asistente,Compro_Pago,Compro_Proove) 
                                                             VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
        info =  Numero_Pres,Cliente,Fecha_Soli,Comercial,Asistente,Compro_Pago,Compro_Proveedor
        cursor.execute(query, info)
        print("save")
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
```

se que me falta usar try except pero por ahora con las pruebas no lo estoy usando

Gracias por leer mi post.

Comment: El cambio que hice fue por una coma con respecto a la consulta, aunque lo había corregido aquí en el post, no lo había hecho en mi código